# YUI3: How would I trigger an event?

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

Suppose I have a click event on a link/button/etc.

```
var myButton = Y.one('.button');

myButton.on('click', function() {
   // code
});
```

There is something else happening on the page that I want to trigger a click event on this button.  How would I do this?

I saw YUI3's fire() method, but it looked like that was designed for custom events.  If I am supposed to use fire(), then will `myButton.fire('click')` work?

(I'm looking for the equivalent of jQuery's .trigger() method, which works on DOM events or custom events.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to trigger the click event on the button? Take the HTML below

```
    <button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
<br>
    <a href="#">Click Me</a>
```

You can make use of the custom events to put the real logic somewhere central.

```
YUI().use("node","event",function(Y){
    Y.one("#myButton").on("click",function(){Y.fire("custom:doThing")});
    Y.all("a").on("click",function(){Y.fire("custom:doThing")});
    Y.on("custom:doThing",function(){console.log("Do my thing, regardless of event source")})
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WZZmR/

Comment: In this case, I don't need to trigger the click event on the button, and your idea is perfectly valid.  However, I wanted to know if YUI could fire a normal DOM event in situations where I may not be able to modify the code.  The YUI docs say fire() is only for custom events.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for equivalent of trigger in yui3 you can try using the 'simulate'

```
Y.one('button selector').simulate('click');
```

For the above statement to work you will need to add "node-event-simulate" roll up in the use method.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to simulate the full event.  simulate() doesn't do that, and is not meant for user-facing code.

Comment: yes, you are correct and they should be used for automation testing.why don't you try using Synthetic events in yui3 ?

Comment: That was suggested by user barnyr below.  I an try synthetic/custom events.  Thanks.